# Running the selenium-standalone npm package on an Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, selenium, ubuntu, server, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run `selenium-standalone` on an Ubuntu server from Digital Ocean. I ssh into the server, then run these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm default-jre
npm install selenium-standalone -g
selenium-standalone install
selenium-standalone start
```

That leads to a nice message that the selenium standalone server is running! **But** when I try to connect to it from a simple script on my computer:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .usingServer('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:4444/wd/hub')
      .build();
```

I get two huge error messages. On the server, I get:

```
23:49:09.596 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]])
23:49:09.599 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e) on port 13700
Only local connections are allowed.
23:49:09.644 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-nodesele', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-nodesele', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-nodesele', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    ... 14 more
23:49:09.653 WARN - Exception: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-nodesele', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

And on my computer, trying to connect to the server, I get:

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-nodesele', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-47-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at createDriver (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:623:16)
    at new Bot (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/test.js:17:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/liamgray/webdriverio-test/test.js:122:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

It seems like the errors are saying that Chrome wasn't installed on the server correctly. But I thought that was supposed to happen during the `selenium-standalone install` command?

Any pointers in the right direction are welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selenium-standalone package installs selenium & it's browser drivers not the browser itself.

Selenium need its browser driver to interact with a specific browser. In your case it needs the chrome driver and it's installed on the server. But you don't have the browser.

You can install chrome by refering to [this page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable). I recommend installing google-chrome-stable

Comment: To add to this answer, (which I believe is the correct one) you might also need something like `Xvfb` to run your browser *in*, serverside. This post helped me get what I needed in a similar environment to yours: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Comment: Wow...this answer saved my life. This is the solution to getting selenium to run on ubuntu with a headless browser.